# To understand synthesis of e-NOS and n-NOS with respect to Ca and calmodulin

Tags: biochemistry, physiology

I found this sentence in my notes interesting

> E-NOS and n-NOS are Ca-calmodulin dependent ferments.
>   They are synthesized in small concentration as a response to physiological signals which increases the level of Ca<sup>2+</sup> in cell.

**Does it mean that e-NOS and n-NOS are synthesized by mediation of Ca and calmodulin?**

I remember how RNS can be derived from nitric oxide and superoxide.
**Are e-NOS and n-NOS expressed on macrophages after induction by cytokines and microbial products, notably interferon-gamma and lipopolysaccharide?**

Comment: What is the reference for your notes? Can you cite a valid reference?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot. This is a classroom discussion, mostly based on current textbooks in Physiology and Pathophysiology. Good bet would be in Robbins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that e-NOS and n-NOS are synthesized by mediation of Ca
>   and calmodulin?

Calmodulin is activated by binding to calcium and NOS is activated by binding to Ca<sup>2+</sup>-calmodulin. The binding changes the structural conformation which renders the enzyme active. See [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22486744).

> Are e-NOS and n-NOS expressed on macrophages after induction [...]

Macrophages generally express iNOS upon induction by cytokines. The activity of iNOS is shown to be different in humans compared to mice; humans have low activity <sup>[[ref](http://www.jleukbio.org/content/81/3/579.full)]</sup>. However mouse macrophages have [been shown](http://www.jbc.org/content/278/29/26480.full) to express eNOS constitutively and eNOS-knockout mice show reduced NFkB production and iNOS induction.